# How I can grant Users a different permission on the Calendar list, from the site collection where the calendar exists

Tags: list, permissions, calendar

I have a community site and I define the users who can contribute, visit, and admin for the community site.
Next I define two calendar lists inside the community list site collection.
Currently the contributors of the community site are contributes of the calendars. But my requirements are:-

1. That I need to define different permissions for users on the calendar and on the site collection.

I access the calendar list permission, and I select to stop permission inheritance. Then I removed the users from the contributor groups, but i I found that they were also removed from the community site list!.
So I need to know who I can have different permission levels for the community site and for the calendar lists. This is because the calendars should only be editable (add new events) by the site admin, while other users should only be able to seen the calendar and its evets. While inside the community site collection users can add, reply to discussion (they are contributors).

Answer (score 1):

Who is member of which SharePoint group is defined at the Site Collection level and you can't change that at a lower level (Site, List, Folder or Item).

What you can change at the lower levels is which permissions Groups and users have.

So when you've broken inheritance then you can remove the contributors group from the list (or change their permissions) and add other groups/users and give those contribute rights.

Answer (score 1):

A SharePoint group is a collection of users, not a permission level in and of itself. You mentioned that you "removed the users from the contributor groups"; this means that you have a group to which you have granted Contribute permissions on your site. I'll call this group **Site Contributors.**

What you want to do is to create a brand new SharePoint group. Call it **Calendar Contributors.** When you create the group, *do not set any permissions at all* from the `Create Group` dialog. After you create the group, if you go to Site Permissions, you will not see it (because you didn't give it any permissions); this is expected.

Next, go to your calendar's permission settings. First, to make things simpler, reset the calendar back to the site's default permissions by clicking `Inherit Permissions`, then `Stop Inheriting Permissions`.

Now, check the box beside your **Site Contributors** group and select `Edit User Permissions`. Uncheck `Contribute` and check `Read`, then click `OK`.

Finally, click `Grant Permissions`. Type **Calendar Contributors** into the `Select Users` box, select `Grant users permission directly` and check the box for `Contribute`. You can uncheck the `Send E-Mail` box as well. Click `OK`.

Now, just add users to your **Calendar Contributors** group if you want them to be able to create and edit calendar items. Users in **Site Contributors** will have all the same access they had before to the rest of the site, but will only have **Read** access to the calendar, unless they're *also* in **Calendar Contributors.**